# How to rotate a matrix (nested list) counter clockwise by 90 degrees

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to rotate a matrix counter clockwise by 90 degrees. 
For example, if:

```
m = [[1,2,3],
     [2,3,3],
     [5,4,3]]
```

then the result should be

```
m = [[3,3,3],
     [2,3,4],
     [1,2,5]]
```

So far, I found:

```
rez = [[m[j][i] for j in range(len(m))] for i in range(len(m[0]))]
    for row in rez:
        print(row)
```

This gives me

```
[1, 2, 5]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 3, 3]
```

This is close, but the rows would need to be reverses. Does anyone know a simple way to rotate this matrix counter clockwise by 90 degrees?

Comment: Here you do not *rotate*, you *transpose*.

Comment: You can here use `numpy` with `np.rot90(m)`.

Comment: `list(zip(*m))[::-1]`

Answer (score 4):

You could do the following:

```
m = [[1, 2, 3],
     [2, 3, 3],
     [5, 4, 3]]

result = list(map(list, zip(*m)))[::-1]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[3, 3, 3],
 [2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 5]]
```

With `map(list, zip(*m))` you create an iterable of the columns, and with the expression `list(...)[::-1]` you convert that iterable into a list and reverse it.

Comment: how would you do this for clockwise instead of counter

Answer (score 0):

What you here basically do is map a matrix *A* to a matrix *B* such that:

*B<sub>i j</sub>=A<sub>j i</sub>*

In case you *rotate* elements, that means that if you rotate an *n×m*-matrix, then that means that:

*B<sub>i j</sub>=A<sub>j n-i</sub>*

So we can calculate this as:

```
rez = [[m[j][ni] for j in range(len(m))] for ni in range(len(m[0])-1, -1, -1)]
```

which is thus the transpose, but than "reversed". Using indices is however typically *not* how you do such processing in Python, since now it works only for items that are subscriptable, so I advice you to look for a more elegant solution.

But that being said, numpy offers a [**`numpy.rot90`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html) function to rotate matrices:

```
>>> np.rot90(m)
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to use [scipy.ndimage.rotate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html)

> Rotate an array.
>
> The array is rotated in the plane defined by the two axes given by the
>   axes parameter using spline interpolation of the requested order.

```
import numpy as np
from  scipy import ndimage

m = np.matrix([[1,2,3],
               [2,3,3],
               [5,4,3]])

ndimage.rotate(m, 90.0) #angle as float.
```

> ```
> Out: 
> array([[3, 3, 3],
>        [2, 3, 4],
>        [1, 2, 5]])
> ```

---

> Same result you can get by using the `zip()` function to transpose rows and columns of a [5.1.4. Nested List](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) then reverse the nested list with `[::-1]` + put in a [np.matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) :

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3],
          [2, 3, 3],
          [5, 4, 3]]

np.matrix(list(zip(*matrix)))[::-1]
```

> ```
> Out: 
> matrix([[3, 3, 3],
>         [2, 3, 4],
>         [1, 2, 5]])
> ```